# iAd banner deform my scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad

I just add an iAd banner to my sprite kit game but it deform the scene because there are balloons in my scene and with iAd banner the balloons are not rounded anymore.

So what I did is to change the property from

```
SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
```

to

```
SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFit
```

So the balloons look rounded again but I have vertical black strips at the left and the right of my scene.

Any solution to remove the black strips ? or to keep rounded balloons with aspectFill ?

Thank you ! SDK iOS 8, Xcode 6.4

Answer (score 0):

You added the iAd banner. It has fixed height. To still keep all of your scene visible iOS has to scale the size of your scene. `AspectFill` will just make the Scene fit the view, and resizes it also not proportional.

AspectFit uses an proportional scale so there must be space on the left and the right. The only thing you can do to avoid black spaces and keep the scene proportinal.

The only thing you can do is to resize the scene:

```
[MyScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(skView.bounds.size.width, skView.bounds.size.height - 50)];
```

(Assuming the iAd banner is 50pt)

Comment: Ok now the scene is still verticaly stretch, so I set up AspectFill, but the scene is centered, need to anchor it at the top, to let the 50px space at the bottom

Comment: @user3722523 Instead of resizing the scene consider resizing the view, because it's anchored in the upper left.

Comment: @user3722523 Yes, you can do that. Or resize the scene in interface builder, what is most likely easier.